# How to count rows in one column with condition with group by or distinct on another column?

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

Is there any way to calculate count of ACCOUNT of distinct ID where STATUS is Approved in power bi ???
Please see the image below. Thanks appreciate

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no relationship between `Table2` and `Table1`, a possible solution might be implemented using `TREATAS` to build the relationship over the `ID` column and `SUMMARIZE(Table1,  Table1[ID], Table1[Account] )` to remove duplicates in `Table1`

```
# approved accounts =
VAR ApprovedIDs =
    TREATAS (
        CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table2[ID] ), Table2[Status] = "Approve" ),
        Table1[ID]
    )
VAR Table1Filtered =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZE ( Table1, Table1[ID], Table1[Account] ),
        ApprovedIDs
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( Table1Filtered )
```

if a one to many relationship exists from `Table2` to `Table1`, then there is no need to use `TREATAS`, since it's enough to leverage the existing relationship

```
# approved accounts =
VAR Table1Filtered =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZE ( Table1, Table1[ID], Table1[Account] ),
        Table2[Status] = "Approve"
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( Table1Filtered )
```

Comment: appreciate. Is there any recommended book/tutorials i can use to learn advance dax ???

Comment: The Definitive Guide to DAX https://www.sqlbi.com/books/ and the free video courses on the same site

Comment: i came to another issue where I have separate ID table which has less number of ID values and have to take ID values from this table so at the end I will be using three table; ID table, table 1 and table 2, is there any way to have number of counts of ACCOUNT where status is approved on distinct IDs ? all tables are connected

Comment: This is a different scenario. Please, write a new question adding some sample data using markdown tables, and the expected output. To create the markdown table this site helps https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/

Answer (score 0):

If your **Table1** and **Table2** are joined through **ID** column, You can use this below **Measure** for your purpose-

```
count_approved_id = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[id]),
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        RELATED(Table2[status]) = "approve"
    )
) + 0
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: appreciate. Is there any recommended book/tutorials i can use to learn advance dax ???